# What frequency photons are involved in mediating physical force?

Tags: forces, photons, electromagnetic-radiation

If the force felt when pushing an object is mediated by the electromagnetic interaction and hence photons, what is their frequency?

Answer (score 4):

The electrostatic force is mediated by virtual photons and one could say that they are not physical photons and they do not have a frequency, i.e. one could claim your question is invalid.

However, one may also determine the frequency from the energy $E$ of the virtual photons (via $E=hf$) which actually *is* determined in each Feynman diagram, although the energy-momentum doesn't satisfy $E^2-p^2 c^2 = m_0^2c^4$ in general. The energy is equal, by energy conservation law, to $E_{1,{\rm final}}-E_{1,{\rm initial}}$. For the electrostatic force that only marginally changes the velocity of the charged particles, you have
$$E=0$$

Comment: Wouldn't Efinal - Einitial give the sum of the energies of the virtual photons? There is no way to determine how many virtual photons contribute,  is there?

Comment: Coulomb gauge FTW  :)

Comment: @FrankH: the transferred energy does not determine the virtual photon frequency since the transferred energy is a result of action of many virtual photons of different frequencies.

Comment: @Vladimir that is exactly what I said...

Comment: Surely you mean $E \approx 0$, in which case the frequency would not be 0 but merely very low - and in that case it would be nice to have an idea of what its average magnitude would be in, for example, the case of a charged comb picking up bits of paper. But I don't know how to calculate that because I don't know how to tell how many photons would be involved.

Comment: My take on this is that when physicists say things like "the electrostatic force is mediated by photons", they mean a very specific thing and not at all "there are photons flying back and forth between the charged particles", but when that phrasing leaks into the general population, it gets vastly misinterpreted. It is very hard for an amateur to navigate this minefield of misunderstanding and misleading phrasing...

Comment: Well, they mean something specific and it's still true, in some vague sense, that photons are flying back and forth, except that all these things have to be described properly by the maths of quantum field theory and who doesn't learn the maths can't really understand the meaning of the phrases whatever the wording is. There isn't any non-mathematical way to make the phrasing less misleading, @romkyns.

Answer (score 1):

Their frequency is determined with the velocities. For example, if you have a heavy, moving with $\vec{v}= const$ source charge that creates a time-dependent potentials $\phi(\vec{x},t)$ and $\vec{A}(\vec{x},t)$, then the Fourier expansions of those potentials will contain the following time-dependent exponentials: $\phi_{\vec{k}}, \vec{A}_{\vec{k}}\propto exp(-i\vec{k}\vec{v}t)$, i.e. the frequencies $\omega=\vec{k}\vec{v}$ are related to the wave vectors in a different way than for the true photons. Any probe charge will feel these "frequencies" in a superposition, as a unique time-dependent force $e\vec{E}(t)+\frac{e}{c}[\vec{V}_p ,\vec{B}(t)]$.

Also, the number of those "photons" is uncertain, that makes the notion of virtual photons a useless concept.

Finally, the transferred energy for a given scattering angle is determined solely with kinematics (the same for any kind of interaction potential), so the notion of the virtual photon is worthless.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Looks like a good answer to me.

Comment: I have a negative initial credit by default ;-)