# Experiment validating existence of virtual particle

Tags: energy, hydrogen, virtual-particles

I'm curious about virtual particle whether do they really exists, therefore I dug out an experimental theory called lamb shift by measuring the difference between the two energy levels of a hydrogen atom since the virtual particle only interact with one of the state. Can explain how the virtual particle contributes to the lamb shift effect?

Comment: AFAIK there is no experiment which can't be explained without virtual particles, so it's not so clear whether they exist or not.

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate, but you might be interested to read [The virtual particles are only a fictive tool in equations? DO they exist or DON'T? And if they exist, why do we call them VIRTUAL?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/147096/the-virtual-particles-are-only-a-fictive-tool-in-equations-do-they-exist-or-don)

Comment: I came across an interesting article see http://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/virtual-particles-what-are-they/

Comment: "Virtual particle" is a name given to lines in Feynman diagrams. To say that they "exist" or not is a meaningless thing to say.

Comment: My answer here might give some leads http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/147035/do-virtual-photons-have-a-frequency/147045#147045